# Is this check-splitting patent valid?

Tags: prior-art, software, us20120036028

Application [US20120036028](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120036028)

So basically this is check splitting...

We have been working on a system for the last year and a half that has the same "feature". By advice from our legal counsel, there was nothing novel about it and would not pass the USPTO examination so we didn't pursue it.

Don't a handful of apps already use such a mechanism?

Should we have pursued a patent?

So would this patent be valid?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you might want to be mindful that what your attorney tells you is privileged so long as both of you protect that privilege.  Lots of time and money is sometimes spent defending against demands to divulge opinion of counsel.

Whether you should have filed for a patent is impossible to asnwer here.  However, if your patent counsel makes money from filing patent applications, then advice not to file is probably something to take to heart.

The link you provide is for a published patent application.  It has been rejected at least once, and it appears that the applicant has amended the claims in view of an obviousness rejection.  There is no guarantee that any claims will be allowed, or that they will be allowed without additional limiting amendments.

Comment: Yorick, thank you for answering. I don't quite understand what you mean by... "Well, you might want to be mindful that what your attorney tells you is privileged so long as both of you protect that privilege. Lots of time and money is sometimes spent defending against demands to divulge opinion of counsel." I understand the privileged part but the second sentence eludes me. Not a lawyer by the way. Also, for the fact that they advised not to file, and they make money by filing, shows great character on their behalf. They could have taken my money and filed with an unsatisfactory outcome.

Comment: Did I divulge something I shouldn't have? Just trying to understand. I come from engineering background but not a lawyer and any help would be greatly appreciated. And yes, lawyers do cost a lot, so I understand the monetary reference. :)

Comment: Attorney-client privilege allows you to communicate freely with your counsel without having to worry that those communications will be used against you, for example at a patent infringement trial to show that you knew about a patent and infringed anyway (even if you thought it was invalid). http://www.patentlyo.com/patent/2006/11/caution_disclos.html

Comment: Does this mean, if this patent is granted, and we had the same mechanisim in place, that the comment on the original post, can waive such rights as attorney-client privilage and be used against us?

Comment: Yorick, do you have any advice on how to go about applying for a patent? You seem to know a lot, and I don't know if you are a lawyer or not, but some links or literature that you can point me to would be greatly appreciated. Just about to start reading Patent It Yourself. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.  There is a link in my profile that might be helpful.  The patentlyo.com website posted in the comments above provides excellent patent information.

Comment: Regarding the privilege: inventors and their attorneys or agents and others involved with a patent submission have a duty of candor and disclosure to the USPTO during the process of applying for a patent. No privilege in anything related to patentability of your invention as it goes through the system.

Comment: @ Mr. White.  You say between an attorney and a client, there is absolutely "[n]o privilege in anything related to patentability of [the client's] invention as it goes through the system."  Do I misquote you?

Comment: Not exactly. The privilege exists in courts. In contrast, dealing with the USPTO has requirement of candor and disclosure that applies to everyone involved in the inventing and patenting process. Anything that might contribute to the examiner issuing a rejection and anything that they know of that contradicts a position previously taken must be disclosed. Also, the examiner can, but rarely does, issue a request for information regarding the circumstances of the invention. This applies to the patenting process, not to a court proceeding. http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-2000.pdf

Comment: It is a good thing we have lawyers providing both facts and opinions about legal matters here.